# To test differentiability of the function $f(z)=z \operatorname{Re}z$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $z=x+iy.$ Then $f(z)=z \operatorname{Re}z=x^2+ixy$. So CR equations are satisfied at $(0,0)$ and partial derivatives $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ are continuous at $(0,0).$ Hence $f(z)=z \operatorname{Re}z$ is differentiable at $(0,0).$

I want to know is there any other way to approach this problem and is there any correction required.

Comment: Are you saying that CR is satisfied, or just that you need to show whether they are satisfied? Because it looks like you are seeing that they are satisfied.

Comment: CR equations are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (which is what I'd start with) is to just apply the definition: for any $h\neq 0$,
\begin{align}
\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}&=\text{Re}(h)
\end{align}
and this approaches $0$ as $h\to 0$. Thus, $f$ is complex-differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing it is:
$$z\Re(z)=z\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}=\frac12(z^2+|z|^2)$$

Comment: yes of course, i'll edit now